# Symfony2: Routing controllers and views in subdirectories

Tags: symfony, url-routing

I'm developing a bundle with frontend and backend. I follow instructions about the best way to structure controllers and views for backend and frontend parts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012191/symfony2-conceptual-issue-general-bundles-vs-specific-ones) and [here](http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2011/05/19/symfony2-bundle-structure-a-use-case.html). But I can't find how to specify subdirectories in my routing configuration file. I try to put this, but it does not work.

```
post:
  pattern:  /
  defaults: { _controller: "HavactBlogBundle:Backend/Post:Backend/index" }
```

Comment: Doesn't simple `:` work? `HavactBlogBundle:Backend:Post:index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I relsoved exposing my controller as service

```
post:
pattern:  /
defaults: { _controller: "my.controller.service.id:indexAction" }
```

Answer (score 16):

try this: replace the slash with the backslash

```
post:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: "HavactBlogBundle:Backend\Post:index" }
```

Comment: The Backslash scape next character "P" and result this error: Unable to find controller "HavactBlogBundle:Backend ost". I resolved with bouble backslash and works for controller, but not for template. index is in backend subdirectory, what i need is something like this HavactBlogBundle:Backend\\Post:Backend/Post/index

Comment: when u want to render the template in action index use this: `return $this->render('HavactBlogBundle:Backend:Post:index.html.twig');`

Comment: Yes, this works to render templates inside an action, but not in the routing config file. defaults: { _controller: "HavactBlogBundle:Backend:Post:index.html.twig" }

Comment: I believe it is "doable" by making it like this: 
{ _controller: "HavactBlogBundle:Backend/Post:index.html.twig" }
the convention with semicolons says something like "bundle:dir:file", where Your dir is "Backend/Post".

Answer (score 5):

For those people not wanting to expose their controllers as a service (which is an indirect solution to the problem), you specify the route as such.

`route_name:
    path:     /path
    defaults: { _controller: BundleName:Namespace/Controller:action }`

`Namespace` is your subdirectory in the bundle's `Controller` directory followed by `/` to separate it.

All else should work just the same.

Comment: Works for me in Symfony 2.7. Slash for separation is fine - it's just important to remember correcting the namespace of those controllers moved to a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

In routing YAML:

```
defaults: { _controller: Org\FancyBundle\Controller\Page\Blog\CommentsController::fancyAction }
```

The difference here is that I don't use quotes around the string and YAML is okay with that.
In a Twig template:

```
{% render "Org\\FancyBundle\\Controller\\Page\\Blog\\CommentsController::listAction" with {} %}
```

I've never had any problems with escaping that I know of. Symfony 2.0.9, PHP 5.3.9 on Windows/IIS (sigh)