# How to handle common table between two Symony2 bundles?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working with Symfony2.0.12 and Doctrine2.1.6.

If you have a DB table "Address", two Symfony2 bundles "UserB" and "CompanyB", two DB tables "UserT" and "CompanyT", (each one with a foreign key referencing table "Address"),

what is the best way to handle this?

- To arbitrarily insert the Address entity in UserB (or CompanyB) and to use only one Address.orm.yml?
- To create another bundle AddressBundle
- Something else?

Comment: in your case I would go with the solution presented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025278/symfony-2-bundles-am-i-using-them-right/10025644#10025644

Comment: Thanks, but I chose to create a HelperBundle that stores all metadatas and entities