# Symfony2: Bundle Structure

Tags: symfony, structure, bundles

My current bundle structure is like this:

1. Acme/CoreBundle
2. Acme/ImageBundle
3. Acme/SecurityBundle
4. Acme/UserBundle
5. Acme/GroupBundle

The CoreBundle holds the edge functionalities like home, contact and imprint.
Now I want to merge the ImageBundle (and later on other global services) into the CoreBundle.
After merging the CoreBundle is too big and confusing so I want to put the edge functionalitites whereelse.
The question is where?

Should I put them into an EdgeBundle?
Where do you store the main, low logic, edge files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See two related questions and my answers to them:

- [Symfony2 conceptual issue: general bundles vs. specific ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012191/symfony2-conceptual-issue-general-bundles-vs-specific-ones)
- [Should everything really be a bundle in Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999433/should-everything-really-be-a-bundle-in-symfony-2)

Comment: Hi, I read through alot of threads and my current opinion is this:
A Bundle represents one component. The hard thing was just to decide what to to with "features" which are to small for an independent Bundle. So I think I will use an AppBundle which holds such edge data (home, contact, imprint), a CommonBundle which holds tools like Paginator, ImageServices, etc. and the additional Components. Let's see how long it takes until this changes again :)