# Best way to manage/share common translation strings between bundles

Tags: symfony, internationalization

I read official docs about translation and i18n and say that xliff files must be put inside bundle or in app/Resources/translations directory. I have many bundles with your own strings, but some strings are used in others bundles too. Which is best strategy to manage/share common translation strings between bundles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I [don't use bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999433/should-everything-really-be-a-bundle-in-symfony-2) for app specific code, so I keep all resources — views, translations, assets, etc — in `app/Resources`. You could consider this approach as well.

Otherwise, if you think you really need bundles, you could keep common translations in `app/Resources/translations` — or `CommonBundle` which I lately [suggest to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012191/symfony2-conceptual-issue-general-bundles-vs-specific-ones) — while keeping the bundle specific translations in themselves.

Comment: I like your approach very much :). I always said. Could work my OrderBundle without my ProductBundle? Definitively not. I think will put all code together now

Comment: One problem with this that you cannot build translation files automatically with _console translation:update_.