# Symfony2: multiples apps, one shared translations folder

Tags: symfony

I have a multiple apps project looking like this

```
/apps/app1
/apps/app2
/apps/app3
/apps/config
/src
/vendor
/web/app1
/web/app2
/web/app3
```

Each app has its kernel, console, cache, ... But how do I share common translations ?

I read there https://stackoverflow.com/a/11630933/689429 that on a one-app structure, you can use `app/Resources/translations`. How about a multiples-apps structure ?

I wish I could make `/apps/Resources/translations` that would be autoloaded (or loaded manually) in all my apps but is it even possible ?

Comment: Could you use symbolic links from /apps/Resources/translations to the individual apps/app1/Resources/translations directories? I know this isn't ideal...

Comment: Yes I could but it means there is no way to have app specific translations AND apps common translations. I will do this if I can't find other solutions. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

Haven't tried it yet, but perhaps the following is possible:

Write and register an EventListener on `kernel.request` in one of your apps and inject the translator service in it, so you are able to modify it. Maybe it needs to be executed before the `LocaleListener` which means it has to have a `priority` higher than *16* to be executed before.

Then in the `onKernelRequest()` method of your event listener, you could then call the `Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator::addResource()` method to add translation files on the fly.

See: http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.html#method_addResource

The parameter `$resource` contains the path to your global translation files.

(What you are trying to do really is an edge case, but there has to be *some* method to do it without symlinking everything.)

Hope this thought helps. I'll try it out as soon as possible and post my results and how I've done it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I'll try it out asap. Theoretically, it should work. I'll set this answer as "accepted" as soon as I have my results.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Note that you perhaps have to register this event listener in all your apps anyway since those event listeners theoretically only work on requests in the app they're registered in, but at least your translation files will be centralized. As I said, I'll try it out as well myself because this really is an interesting use case you're having. If you're sucessful, could you provide your solution?