# Symfony2 Bundles

Tags: symfony, bundle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For what would I make a bundle? (Symfony 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935213/for-what-would-i-make-a-bundle-symfony-2)

I'm just learnging Symfony2 and following the symblog tutorial. However, I am just wondering what type of bundles you should create for a full website. Do create one bundle for the whole site which contains all controllers etc for the site or if a website contains a login section, news section, blog etc would you have a separate bundle for each as well as one "master" bundle for the general web pages such as About Us, Contact Us, Homepage etc?

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this is a duplicate. As I understan, I should create 1 "master" bundle (appBundle or coreBundle) that will have the basic website and then for special parts which could be used for other projects (login, news, blog etc) create their own bundle?

Comment: Actually after reading into this more, I think login, news and blog would be in the appBundle or coreBundle as they share the same model with the website and only things which can be used for other projects without modification should be in their own bundle i.e pagination. Is that correct?

Comment: yes - that's correct. You can consider create separate bundle if your answer for question "can i get this whole bundle and apply to completely different project without any problems?" will be positive :)