# Where do you put your homepage in Symfony2 Project?

Tags: symfony, bundle

As Symfony2 said, everything in the framework is bundle. So, your website will also be a bundle. As far as I could understand from http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html, bundle represents a feature, and that means everytime I want to add a new feature, I must create a new bundle.

For example, I want to create a website which have Blog features and Event Features. Then I will have 2 bundles, BlogBundle and EventBundle. Every code related to Blog will be housed under BlogBundle, and Event in EventBundle.

My question is, where should I put the homepage? or maybe another page like Contact, About, Terms and Policy, etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these two questions and my answers to them:

- [Symfony2 conceptual issue: general bundles vs. specific ones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8012191/745188)
- [Should everything really be a bundle in Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9999433/745188)

**TL;DR**

Create one app-specific bundle called `AppBundle` to avoid the hardcore decision making process on where to put and then find an entity.