# Application structure in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am quiet new to the symfony framework and took some lessons and purchased the '*Starting in Symfony2*' tutorial from knpuniverse. I want to be sure that I use the correct setup for my application. My question is, How do you call your first central bundle? eg. FrontendBundle? I want to make the next structure in my application:

- FrontendBundle

  - The front where people get a landing site where they can also login

from there, when they login, they get into the next bundle:

- CustomerBundle

  - Backend app where customers get their invoices and pay them and edit their information we stored in the database

And at least:

- AdminBundle

  - Another backend app where I can edit customers, make invoices for customers and edit the app information

Is this the correct way and is FOSUserBundle a good bundle for this kind of application?

Comment: Please provide links to external resources wherever you can.

Comment: I think that FOSUserBundle is good for this application. But I think that login page is part of FOSUserBundle.

Comment: @pal4life I cannot provide any links. I am a new user so I cannot post external links within my posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundles have sense only if they can be used in "multiple projects". I mean: if you write code, make it as a bundle and you can't reuse that bundle (for example because bundles, as you described above, are strictly and logically connected to your project) this three bundle separations is totally useless.

### So, final answer (that is also a question) is:

*Could you reuse FrontendBundle in other projects?

Could you reuse CustomBundle in other projects?

Could you reuse AdminBundle in other porjects?*

If you notice that you can't use any or all of these bundles for other project, maybe this separations isn't good.

### Why I say that?

Because if they can't be used in separated ways is *likely* that they should be used togheter so you should keep them togheter.

So I advice to keep them into a single bundle (YourNameYourBundleNameBundle (in that notation, for example)) and to separate the single "areas":

- FrontEnd controllers/entities/views
- Custom controllers/entities/views
- Admin controllers/entities/views

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is clear that I need to put the whole project in a single bundle, including fosuserbundle.

Comment: @RicardoJ: wait a minute, FOSUserBundle should be "integrate" within your bundle but not inserted into. With integrated I mean that you should "link" the FOS using config and routings

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been discussed at length already. For application specific code either [do a single `AppBundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8012191/745188) or [don't use bundles at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9999433/745188).